# Django password_change_done viewable only on redirect from password_change view (on succesful password change)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I require the password_change_done url to be visible only when the password_change view redirects to it (on successful change of password). Otherwise on going to the password_change_done view, it must redirect to the password_change view

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do that is to use the session:

When the `password_change` view is valid and before redirecting to the `password_change_done` view, just set a `password_changed` session attribute to `True`, something like this:

`request.session['password_changed'] = True`

After that, in your `password_change_done` view, check if `password_changed` is True and only then actually display the view, something like:

```
if request.session.get('password_changed'):
    # render password_change_done view
else:
    # redirect to the password_change view
```